# Can clipboard.js be used on a wordpress site?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have not tried doing this yet. I'm curious if anyone has even tried this or if it's even possible.

Thank you!

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. do some research .if you got any error then post it here .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WordPress** is a PHP CMS, So it's not related to JavaScript, So you can use any JavaScript code / library / framework you want.

The final answer is **Yes you can**

Comment: Great! Thanks.... I'll give it a go. :)